# If $n$ has $r$ odd prime divisors then $2^r | \phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

> Let $\phi (n)$ be the Euler totient function $n\in \Bbb N$. If $n$ has $r$ odd prime divisors then $2^r | \phi(n)$

If $n$ is prime then $\phi(n)= n-1$ except $2$ all primes are odd therefore $n-1$ would be even and $2^r$ a divisor.

What should I do if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: Perhaps the correct statement is "If $n$ has $r$ odd prime divisors, ....".

Answer (score 3):

()= [(${p}_{1}^{k_1}$) ... (${p}_{r}^{k_r}$)][($p_1$ -1) ... ($p_r$ -1)].
For every i such that 0 < i < (k + 1), ($p_i$ -1) is even. Therefore you can re-write the equation replacing the ($p_i$ -1) portions with 2 times an integer: 
()= [($p_{1}^{k_1}$) ... ($p_{r}^{k_r}$)][(2)($m_1)$ ... (2)($m_r$)] = [$(p_{1}^{k_1}) ... (p_{r}^{k_r})][(2^r)(m_1 ... m_r)]$, where $m_1 ... m_r$ are integers.

Thus $2^r$|().

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is not prime, then $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$, and $\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)$. Rewriting the parenthetical as $\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}$,we see that $p_i$ will divide $n$ (since each $\alpha_i\geq 1)$ and there are $r$ terms of $p_i-1$ each of which is even (since $p_i$ are odd). Hence $2^r$ will divide the numerator.

Comment: We were given that there are $r$ odd prime divisors, so $2$ is not a problem.